# Анимированная строка в инпуте

Tags: javascript

Суть задачи в том, что есть два инпута, в одном инпуте вводиться строка, во втором инпуте она с анимацией выводится. Попробовал реализовать, но моя идея не сработала. Отладчик ругается на условие if. И еще подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать дополнительно остановку и старт анимации по нажатию на кнопки?

```js
var speed = 100;
var i = 0;
function line() {
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
var value = test.value;
    console.log(value);
   if (i++ < value.length) document.getElementById('result') = value.substring(0, i);
    else {
        //document.getElementById('result') = " ";
        i = 0;
    }
    to = setTimeout("line()", speed);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Введите строку!" id="test">
<input id = "result" value = "Здесь появится результат." disabled>
<button onclick="line()">Нажми</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var speed = 100;
var i = 0;
var to = null;

function line() {
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    var value = test.value;
    //console.log(value);
    if (i++ < value.length) document.getElementById('result').value = value.substring(0, i);
    else {
        //document.getElementById('result') = " ";
        i = 0;
    }
    to = setTimeout("line()", speed);
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = stop;
}

function stop () {
    clearTimeout(to);
    //document.getElementById('result').value = " ";
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = line;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Введите строку!" id="test">
<input id = "result" value = "Здесь появится результат." disabled>
<button id = "click" onclick="line()">Нажми</button>
```

Comment: Я прошу конечно прощения, но дело было всего-навсего в `.value`??

Comment: @Mr.Flatman, ну это да, а сейчас я ещё напишу код остановки таймера

Comment: спасибо буду ждать

Comment: @Mr.Flatman, готово

Comment: спасибо большое, пойду разбирать и смотреть :)